# Find timestamps in pandas dataframe that are at least 30 minutes apart but not at regular 30 minute intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm looking for a faster/more clever way to do what I'm currently doing.

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns of interest, 'DateTime' and 'Value'. I want to find all rows in which Value exceeds a certain threshold, but with 30 minute windows. The 30 minute window begins the first time Value > threshold (in a grouping).

So let's say threshold = 0.5 and we have the following rows.

```
DateTime,Value
2021-07-06 09:00:00,0.4
2021-07-06 09:01:00,0.51
2021-07-06 09:02:00,0.55
2021-07-06 09:03:00,0.56
2021-07-06 09:04:00,0.49
2021-07-06 09:05:00,0.51
2021-07-06 09:29:00,0.2
2021-07-06 09:30:00,0.6
2021-07-06 09:31:00,0.1
2021-07-06 09:45:00,0.7
2021-07-06 09:46:00,0.8
```

So in this case, the first row to be returned is 9:01, and the next is 9:45.

Currently, I find these rows by iterating, and it's very inefficient. Is there a better way that's more vectorized? I have hundreds of these files, millions of lines, many thresholds, and it's taking several hours to complete.

```
import pandas as pd
row_indices = []
threshold_val = 0.5
wait_time = pd.Timedelta(30, unit='m')
df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
rows = df[df['Value'] > threshold_val] 
while len(rows) > 0:
    row_index = rows.first_valid_index()
    row_time = rows['DateTime'][row_index]
    row_indices.append(row_index)
    rows = rows[rows['DateTime'] > row_time + wait_time]
```

Results:

```
df
Out[112]: 
              DateTime  Value
0  2021-07-06 09:00:00   0.40
1  2021-07-06 09:01:00   0.51
2  2021-07-06 09:02:00   0.55
3  2021-07-06 09:03:00   0.56
4  2021-07-06 09:04:00   0.49
5  2021-07-06 09:05:00   0.51
6  2021-07-06 09:29:00   0.20
7  2021-07-06 09:30:00   0.60
8  2021-07-06 09:31:00   0.10
9  2021-07-06 09:45:00   0.70
10 2021-07-06 09:46:00   0.80

row_indices
Out[113]: [1, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
df = df.loc[df.Value > 0.5]
df = df.reset_index()
df["DateTime2"] = df["DateTime"]

print(
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="30min", key="DateTime", origin="start"))
    .first()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Prints:

```
   index  Value           DateTime2
0      1   0.51 2021-07-06 09:01:00
1      9   0.70 2021-07-06 09:45:00
```

The indices are in `index` column: `1` and `9`

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by finding all values above threshold:

```
df2 = df[df.Value > 0.5]
```

Then, group by 30min (+1s to be exclusive) and keep the first value of each group:

```
df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime']) ## make sure DateTime is DateTime type
d.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min1s', key='DateTime')).index.first().values
```

Output:

```
[1,9]
```

Let us know how fast this runs!

Comment: `freq='30min', closed='right'` options work as well

Comment: This and the answer above are very close but not quite right. I am having difficulty getting true exclusivity. My original method will correctly identify 14:40:50 and 15:11:00 as being a 30 min exclusive window. However, pd.Grouper identifies 14:40:50 and 15:10:50. This is using many variations of freq='30min1s' or '30min10s' or '1801s' or '1810s'. closed='right' seems to induce some weird behavior, choosing 13:36:50 and 13:27:00. In reference to the `rows` that I use above 
`df.iloc[rows.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1801s', key='DateTime', origin='start')).first()['index'].values]`

Comment: Can you give an example dataset for which it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: [Data](https://pastebin.com/zmAqb7nf), [Code Snippet](https://pastebin.com/q73rjFXD), [Output](https://pastebin.com/jDKqa3pD)